# Switching detail view of NavigationSplitPane requires back button if nested Navigation Stack

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ipad

I have a main menu using a NavigationSplitView. When I select one of those items in the list, the detail side changes to the corresponding view. That works great.

If you select an item in the subview, you get the detail section of the item you clicked, with a back button to take you back one level.

The problem is, if you are already on the "detail view" and you click on the main menu items from the far left menu, it doesn't change the parent detail pane unless you click on the "back button" that is in the subview. Is there a way to make the subview change instantaneous and not require an additional "back button" press?

```
NavigationSplitView
{
      List(mainMenuItems, selection: $selectedMainMenuItem)
            { item in
                NavigationLink(value: item)
                {
                    Text(item.name)
                }
                
            }
} detail:
        {
            if let selectedMainMenuItem
            {
                switch(selectedMainMenuItem.name)
                {
                case "Link1":
                    SectionView1()
                case "Link2":
                    SectionView2()
                case "Link3":
                    SectionView3()
                default:
                    Text("")
                }
                
            }
            
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how, looks like the navigation link should have a `destination` parameter and a modifer  `.isDetailLink(true)`